# Encrypt and decrypt FormsAuthenticationTicket to authenticate users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, httpmodule

I'm trying to create my own authentication mechanism which relies on `FormsAuthentication`. I'm basically using OAuth to allow users to authenticate in an Authorization Server, and once they are authenticated, I need to use `FormsAuthentication`  to authenticate them across the session. So anyway, I created an `HttpModule` and a helper class to make this work. Unfortunately, it does not.

What happens is that on `PostAuthenticateRequest` I encrypt the ticket and add a cookie to the response, then redirect the user to the root of the website. Once the user is re-directed, another HTTP request is issued so the `HttpModule` is triggered again, and on the `AuthenticateRequest` event I'm checking whether this user is authenticated or not. In order to check if the user is authenticated, I'm trying to read the cookie, get the username from it and then set the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` property. But, for some reason, the cookie cannot be found.

Here's my code:

```
public class OAuthModule : IHttpModule
{
    private const String USERNAME = "username";

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.AuthenticateRequest += context_AuthenticateRequest;
        context.PostAuthenticateRequest += context_PostAuthenticateRequest;
    }

    void context_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var application = sender as HttpApplication;
        if (application != null)
        {
            String username = application.Context.Items[USERNAME].ToString();
            String uri = RemoveQueryStringFromUri(application.Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
            var cookie = IdentityHelper.GetEncryptedFormsAuthenticationCookie(username, uri);
            application.Context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            application.Context.Response.Redirect(uri);
        }
    }

    void context_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = sender as HttpApplication;
        if (sender != null)
        {
            if (!application.Context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("."))
            {
                if (!IdentityHelper.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    HttpContextWrapper wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(application.Context);
                    String clientId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
                    String clientSecret = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];
                    String authorizationServerAddress = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorizationServerAddress"];
                    var client = OAuthClientFactory.CreateWebServerClient(clientId, clientSecret, authorizationServerAddress);
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(application.Context.Request.QueryString["code"]))
                    {
                        InitAuthentication(wrapper, client);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        OnAuthCallback(wrapper, client);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void InitAuthentication(HttpContextWrapper context, WebServerClient client)
    {
        var state = new AuthorizationState();
        var uri = context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        uri = RemoveQueryStringFromUri(uri);
        state.Callback = new Uri(uri);
        var address = "https://localhost";
        state.Scope.Add(address);

        OutgoingWebResponse outgoingWebResponse =  client.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(state);
        outgoingWebResponse.Respond(context);
    }

    private void OnAuthCallback(HttpContextWrapper context, WebServerClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            IAuthorizationState authorizationState = client.ProcessUserAuthorization(context.Request);
            AccessToken accessToken = AccessTokenSerializer.Deserialize(authorizationState.AccessToken);
            String username = accessToken.User;
            context.Items[USERNAME] = username;                
        }
        catch (ProtocolException e)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("OAuth Client", e.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }

    private String RemoveQueryStringFromUri(String uri)
    {
        int index = uri.IndexOf('?');
        if (index > -1)
        {
            uri = uri.Substring(0, index);
        }
        return uri;
    }
}


public class IdentityHelper
{
    public static Boolean IsAuthenticated
    {
        get
        {
            String username = DecryptFormsAuthenticationCookie();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                SetIdentity(username);
                return Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static String DecryptFormsAuthenticationCookie() 
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
            return ticket.UserData;
        }
        return String.Empty;
    }

    internal static HttpCookie GetEncryptedFormsAuthenticationCookie(String username, String domain)
    {
        var expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, username, DateTime.Now, expires, true, username, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
        cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        cookie.Domain = domain;
        cookie.Expires = expires;
        return cookie;
    }

    private static void SetIdentity(String username)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username) });
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally got it solved. It was as simple as the following:

```
application.Context.Response.Redirect(uri, false);
```

I needed to tell the module not to kill the current response (hence the `false`) so it would preserve the cookie in the coming request.